# jQuery dynamic elements like TR and TD, add to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to create dynamic TR and TD elements in an HTML table?  Something similar but better than this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="new-title"]').on('click', function(){
    var table = $('table[name="errortitle"]');
    var tr = $('<tr />');
    var td = $('<td />');
    var input = $('<input />').attr({'class' : 'form-control'})
    var button = $('<button />').attr({'class' : 'btn'});
    var checkbox = input.clone().attr({'type' : 'checkbox', 'name' : 'check'});

    var tdId = td.clone().html('-');
    var tdTitle = td.clone().append(input.addClass('formInput').attr({'type': 'text'}));
    var tdCheckBox = td.clone().append(checkbox);
    var tdAction = td.clone().html(button.addClass('btn-danger').html('Usuń'));

    tr.append(tdCheckBox);
    tr.append(tdId);
    tr.append(tdTitle);
    tr.append(tdAction);

    table.append(tr);
  });
});
```

Is it possible to make this code nicer or more efficient?

Comment: An alternative way should be AngularJS. You can define a default HTML and ride a repeater into this code. For more information: [AngularJS:ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat)

Comment: You can use `insertRow` and `insertCell`; very easy for `tr` and `td`.

Answer (score 9):

You could create a function that will add a row to the table based on the number of elements of data you pass to it (which will become columns):

```
function newRow($table,cols){
    $row = $('<tr/>');
    for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
        $col = $('<td/>').append(cols[i]);
        $row.append($col);
    }
    $table.append($row);
}
```

You can then call this function for every new row you want to make. `$table` expects a jQuery object, `cols` expects an array of elements (DOM or jQuery) to append to the row. I've also tidied up the jQuery that creates your elements. Did you know you can use the second parameter in the jQuery function to set element properties?:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="new-title"]').on('click', function(){
    var table = $('table[name="errortitle"]');

    var tdId = '-';
    var tdTitle = $('<input />', {'class' : 'form-control formInput', 'type': 'text'});
    var tdCheckBox = $('<input />', {'class' : 'form-control', 'type' : 'checkbox', 'name' : 'check'});
    var tdAction = $('<button />', {'class' : 'btn btn-danger', html:'Usuń'});

    newRow(table,[tdCheckBox,tdId,tdTitle,tdAction]);
  });
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/bgfUR/)

Try it with any amount of column data:

```
newRow(table,[tdCheckBox,tdId,tdTitle,tdAction,'another col','and another','a final col']);
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/bgfUR/1/)